What is the word for when somebody does not stop somebody else from doing something?
The action that the person is doing can be illegal. I was thinking of using the word "perpetrator" but I'm not sure as the definitions that i have seen online only use it as the act of doing the crime and not the enabling of it.
ex: they perpetuate his behaviour

Tolerate.
E.g., John knew that every Monday night, his wife went out and robbed a bank but he tolerated her criminal acts.

There is the word bystander but the definition you will find in dictionaries is rather neutral:

a person who is standing near and watching something that is happening but is not taking part in it (Cambridge)

However, in the context of bullying, it takes on a negative connotation:

A bystander is ‘a person who does not become actively involved in a situation where someone else requires help’ (Clarkson 1996, p6) and in this way is understood to be a passive observer, an onlooker who watches something happening, but stays on the sidelines and doesn’t intervene or get help, even if someone needs it. (anti-bullyingalliance)

There is the antithesis between passive and active bystanders:

The bystander has two options: to remain a passive bystander or become an active bystander. A passive bystander is one who observes but does not intervene in any way. (University of Mexico)

